# Insert data from a form using HTTPS protocol using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, https

So I'm developing a simple Facebook contest page using an iFrame with HTTPS since Facebook use this protocol. Users enter some informations and everyone participating are registered in our database.

At first, I developed a short form using the PHP request `($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")`. My application wasn't on a HTTPS secured domain, so everything was working fine. Then I copied the same page in the HTTPS domain so that it could work inside a Facebook tab. Now my Mysql queries are sending errors. I tried to find a tutorial where it explains how to retrieve informations from a PHP form using HTTPS protocols and inserting them inside a local database but I found nothing.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks !

Comment: https is transparent. strip off the encryption and whatnot, and it's just a plain normal boring http form submission. PHP couldn't care less if you submit to http://... or https://...

Comment: What do you mean by "mysql queries are sending errors"?